# Is a Ruby 2.x application vulnerable to Nokogiri 1.13.1 vulnerabilities?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a Ruby 2.5.1 application that uses Nokogiri 1.12.5. `bundle audit` says I should upgrade to Nokogiri 1.13.2, however  "[Update packaged libxml2 (2.9.12 → 2.9.13) and libxslt (1.1.34 → 1.1.35)](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/security/advisories/GHSA-fq42-c5rg-92c2)" states

> Please note that this advisory only applies to the CRuby implementation of Nokogiri < 1.13.2

The Wikipedia page for [CRuby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_MRI) states that Ruby 2.x uses YARV as its interpreter rather than CRuby.
Am I right to conclude that my application is not vulnerable to this issue with Nokogiri?

Please note, I'm aware that Nokogiri 1.13.3 has since been released which reverts one of these fixes, and that I should be on a more up to date Ruby.

Comment: @them, thank you for editing my question. So many mistakes. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade `nokogiri` to the latest possible for your project, especially when dealing with security issues. There are some caveats to this particular advisory, so you *might* not be vulnerable, but when dealing with security it's better to be overly cautious.

The note on Wikipedia refers to the MRI `CRuby` implementation as opposed to the others (like `jruby`).

Comment: I agree that updating rather than delaying is generally a good principle. Also since I wrote my question a better investigation of 1.13.3 reveals that it still fixes both CVE's. A single commit was reverted.  
  

With reference to you saying 
"The note on Wikipedia refers to the MRI CRuby implementation as opposed to the others (like jruby).".   

Please can you clarify. Does that mean that the vulnerability would exist in my code or not?

Comment: If you are not on Jruby, you're most likely using MRI ruby, and using an older version of nokogiri, which means you're most likely vulnerable.

Comment: Thank you @eugen. I also found this page which provides further detail to explain what CRuby is, and has been. https://engineering.appfolio.com/appfolio-engineering/2017/12/28/cruby-mri-jruby-rubyspec-rubinius-yarv-a-little-bit-of-ruby-naming